# OnClick on a TextView to open separate windows for each item

Tags: android

I have an Android application consisting of a textview with images and text that will fetch the data from the array. I would like to each item I have, by clicking, open another page itself for each item.

Comment: Refer https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html to start a new `Activity`. You would add an onclick listener and do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this code used for lists.
The way to send data to another activity is by using Intent Object.
see this example I used one string. hopefully, you get the main idea.

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            // makes list clickable
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    // element in your list
                    String university =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.university)).getText().toString();
                    // Intent object to send data from activity to another
                    Intent sendData = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InformationActivity.class);
                    sendData.putExtra("university", university);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(sendData);
                    //showToast(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
    );
```

then in the activity, you want to show the data

```
// create intent object
    Intent n = getIntent();
    // get the data
    String university = n.getStringExtra("university");
    //set
    universityLabel.setText(university);
```